# Should we mark new questions with accepted answers as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [How to subtract two dates in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794007/how-to-subtract-two-dates-in-php) which looks like a duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php).

Considering the question has an already accepted answer, should it be marked as a duplicate or is this just a waste of time?

Comment: In this very case the accepted answer to the new question is mostly even just a link list. And the proposed duplicate amounts to a thorough reference. So this case is largely indisputable. -- In other instances, it really depends on question genericness, or which of the possible duplicates+answers appears more searchable or conclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When you ask yourself whether you should cast a close vote because of duplication, it really does not matter whether it has an accepted answer or not.**

One of the goals of marking questions as duplicate is to keep only one question about the problem open so that *this one question* can accumulate all the good answers that people propose instead of having these answers be spread about on a dozen duplicates.

So if it is a duplicate, then close.

**However, whether a question has an accepted answer can figure in your decision regarding *which* question to close.** You should vote to close the question which is most worthy of closure: because it is not as high quality as the other, because the answers it has are not good, etc. Having an accepted answer is better than not having one. At the same time this is not the most critical factor. An answer that has been upvoted a few times is better than an answer that has only been accepted but got 0 or 1 upvote. And I've seen accepted answers that were terrible. So...

Comment: For this specific case, @mario marked it as a duplicate which in my opinion was the correct thing to do.