# What to do with an almost-duplicate question with a better answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I ran into a problem with Perl relating to 64-bit Windows, but I didn't know it at the time I wrote the question. After one answer was posted pointing out the 64-bit issue (but not really providing a solution) I self-answered. Here's the question:

[Reading from Windows registry in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30269931/1390430)

Later, I found a question from somebody who knew up front that the problem was 64-bit Windows (pretty much exactly the problem my own answer to my question solves) but that doesn't have any good answers using the module I want to use:

[How do I make the 32-bit Perl read the 64-bit Windows registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2110782/1390430)

(I'm pretty sure Stack Overflow was smart enough to find that question as a "related question" only *after* the 64-bit answers were added, but it's possible I was just not very observant of that column prior to writing my own answer).

I'm somewhat inclined to call these duplicates, since really my problem is pretty much exactly the same as the existing question. But I think my answer is the best from *both* questions, so I'd lean toward marking the existing question as duplicate. This seems shady to me since I provided both the new question *and* the new answer. But I guess [which question to mark as a duplicate is subjuctive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276340/1390430), and if I were *not* involved in these posts, I *think* I'd choose my question/answer.

On the other hand, I was completely unaware of the root cause of my problem being my 64-bit Windows vs. 32-bit Perl. Not knowing the root cause, I certainly did not find the existing question when I looked for one. Since my question was a more general "what could I be doing wrong accessing the registry from Perl?" rather than a specific "how can I access a 64-bit registry view in 32-bit Perl?" then maybe they are not duplicates after all. Since they are related (and probably share the same answer) maybe they [should be merged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269084/1390430)?

How should I handle this (without looking like I'm gaming the system in some way)?

Comment: Only a mod can merge the questions, so you're not really gaming the system in any way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the key:

> I found a question from somebody who knew up front that the problem was 64-bit Windows (pretty much exactly the problem my own answer to my question solves) but that **doesn't have any good answers using the module I want to use**

That's completely fixable.  Simply post an answer to *that* question.  Note that a few changes may be required to fit the context, don't simply cut+paste from your self-answer.

Now that question has all the information needed to solve yours as well, and yours can be safely closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Looking at this again today, I actually think this makes a lot of sense. I would want to also edit my question to point out the reason for the problem in the first place, I think, so it is clear to visitors why it's a duplicate. However, this is only the best solution if this closed question remains around for searching; without knowing in advance that my problem had to do with 64-bit registry keys, I would never have thought to search for that problem. I think nowadays duplicate questions are generally kept for later searchability, correct?

Comment: I went with this, because this way: (1) people finding the *old* question still get the better answer from my question, (2) people finding *my* question have a clear understanding of what the problem was and can still find the answer, and (3) as someone pointed out, if not enough agree these are truly duplicates, then the close vote will expire and no harm is done, but the questions are still marked as clearly related.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, duplicates remain on the site as signposts, pointing to the master question (and single group of answers).

Comment: How can I answer questions that are `borderline duplicates` (but still not duplicates), if my answer for both questions is essentially the same, without being reprimanded for it?! Or what other options do I have? See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293/answering-borderline-duplicate-questions

Answer (score 25):

Almost-duplicate is not duplicate. Both questions could potentially lead many users coming at the problem from somewhat different perspectives (and presumptions such as yours) to the right solution to their problem. I say leave both questions as is. As long as it doesn't unnecessarily add clutter, it's best for the site and best for the people who want to use this site.

Comment: Both questions only lead users to the right solution if they ARE marked as duplicate.  Otherwise, half the solutions are here, and half there, making it hard to find them.

Answer (score 18):

I think you should add a comment in the other question that points to your question as a related question. Add a bit of verbiage in the comment to indicate why your question is related to the other question.

Comment: I would even go further and nominate the old question as a duplicate of your new question. The nomination [will eventually expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire) but it will leave an automated comment pointing to the new question; and if many readers agree that yours is a good canonical answer to the other question, your nomination will gather enough votes to mark the old question as a duplicate of yours.

Comment: Of course, the act of adding that comment may also prompt others to do the nomination.

Answer (score 6):

If you are certain your question and answer is significantly better than the old one, feel free to vote that the old one is a duplicate of the new one.

If you aren't certain, either err on the side of voting that the new one is a duplicate of the old one, or make your new question and answer so much better that you become certain.

I'd want there to be a duplicate link between them, however, as being able to concentrate the google-juice can help people find solutions to problems.

Comment: It looks like there is some precedent for this (related links yet again, geeze): [Duplicate question (but only when you know the answer)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258804/1390430) [Why was my question marked duplicate citing an existing similar answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266364/1390430)

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason to close duplicate questions is to prevent that any effort is spent on writing information which can already be found elsewhere. But (unlike in source code) existing duplicate posts are normally not really a problem, except for a topic where it's expected that updates regarding new versions of some system will be necessary. (If that happens, edit the somewhat-better version; perhaps add anything that was only in the other version, then vote to close the outdated version as duplicate.)

As long as there are just two correct version around, I don't really see any need for action. Adding comments to each question “for further reading” should be quite sufficient.